# Construction of a path of quadratic variation

Tags: real-analysis, stochastic-processes

This question has been posted to Stack Exchange earlier, and no answer is available yet.

Consider a path $x: [0,1] \to \mathbb R$. it's $p$-variation on an interval
 is defined by
$$V_{p}(x, [a, b]) = \lim_{|\Pi| \to 0} \sum_{i=1}^{n}|x(t_{i}) - x(t_{i-1})|^{p}$$
where $\Pi = \{a= t_{0}< t_{1}, \ldots, < t_{n} =b\}$ is a partition and $|\Pi| = 
\max_{i} |t_{i} - t_{i-1}|$ is its mesh size. It is well known that 
a Brownian motion is almost surely quadratic variation path in any subinterval of $[0,1]$, i.e. $V_{2}(B, [a, b]) \in (0,1)$ almost surely for arbitrary $0\le a < b \le 1$.

(Q).  Is there any simple and explicit construction of a single path, which has 
finite positive quadratic variation in any subinterval of $[0,1]$?

Comment: Suggestion: Try to construct a "sawtooth" path $x_0$ which at least has finite positive quadratic variation on any neighborhood $[0, \epsilon]$, by giving it smaller and smaller "teeth" of appropriate size near 0.  Then construct $x$ with rational translates of $x_0$, like $x(t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} x_0(t-q_n)$.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for your suggestions. I got your point. But I am still struggling to make a "sawtooth" at zero.